# How can I tell AngularJS to order by overdue timestamps?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a todo app and, currently, I am ordering by a timestamp associated with each item. My problem is, I want to be able to order by overdue, nearly overdue and upcoming. So, if the time is currently 1PM and an item in the list is set for 12PM, that needs to be at the top, followed by an item set for 1:15PM etc... Is there a way to do this in Angular?

When I do filter by timestamp, it does not order correctly. See here:
[image]

But in my code I have set it to order by timestamp:
    `<tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: 'timestamp'" class="item" data-open="false" style="font-size: 16px;">`

Comment: can put some jsfiddle or plunkr to try help you?

Answer (score 0):

If u can put something code its nice, but to order in angular its easy just like:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'workdate'">
```

And if u want reserve order:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'workdate':true">
```

Hope this help you, or put something code or example (in plunkr or jsfiddle or another) to understand better ;D